# How to Build a Docker Python Image with Plotly?

Tags: python, dockerfile, plotly, alpine-linux

I am having lots of problems creating a Docker container using python:3.6-alpine for Plotly. Plotly also uses Pandas and Numpy. When I run my Dockerfile below, the "RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt" fails. Anyone have recommendations for this, am I missing requirements?

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN adduser -D visualdata

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /home/visualdata

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn
#RUN venv/bin/pip install install python3-pymysql

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY visualdata.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod a+x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP visualdata.py

RUN chown -R visualdata:visualdata ./
USER visualdata

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you include the error you get when building the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Python docker image [official repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), there is a Dockerfile example that illustrates the pip step:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

You should be able to use pip directly instead of venv/bin/pip.

You do not really need to use a virtualenv in a docker container if you are only running one application inside. The container already provides its own isolated environment.

Comment: Hi Victor- after your changes, here is the error output: Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ozezw0la/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-vw8kl0es/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ozezw0la/numpy/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Can you include your requirements.txt? I just tried with a minimal requirements.txt and it worked just fine. It sounds like you are having issues with package versions. You can confirm by trying to build with only one package in your requirements.txt.